# Need to know how to SQL query where all a like model numbers differs in description

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need a query where i can query all model numbers and have it return where the same model numbers have different descriptions. I need this information to make all the description a like for the same model of equipment.

Sample Data:

```
MODEL NUMBER    DESCRIPTION
ASA5520         ASA 5520 adaptive security appliance
ASA5520         Cisco ASA 5520 Appliance
ASA5520         CISCO ASA 5520 APPLIANCE W/ CSC10, SW, 50 USER, 1 YR SUBSCRIPTION
ASA-CSC10       ASA 5500 SERIES CONTENT SECURITY SSM-10 S/W LICENSE
ASA-CSC10       ASA 5500 SERIES CONTENT 
ASA-CSC10       ASA 5500 SSM-10 S/W LICENSE
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data? What did you try so far?

Comment: NOthing so far its hard to search for something like this so i have nothing to try or where to begin. Basically i need a Diff.. Logically its would look like:

IF Model Number is the same AND Descriptions vary
Display Results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
  from test
where
  model_number in (
    select model_number
      from test
  group by model_number
    having count(distinct description) > 1)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4df9bb/9)

Updated to display all descriptions.

Comment: Joe How can I also include all the returned descriptions with the associated models in the results? Or would it just be easier to query the returned model numbers?

Comment: Cool thank you both.. both query returned the results i need!!

Answer (score 2):

Try semi join:

```
select *
from tab t1
where exists(
  select 1
  from tab t2
  where t1.model_number = t2.model_number
    and t1.description <> t2.description
)
order by model_number
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/827f9/2